# Ошибка при попытке поставить сайт yii2 на сервере

Tags: mysql, база-данных, yii2, сервер, composer

При попытке установить сайт на хостинг, мне выдаёт следующую ошибку ( сайт на yii2 )

```
An internal server error occurred.
Fatal error: date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /var/www/**скрыл**/data/www/**скрыл**/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php on line 369
```

Что необходимо сделать, чтоб исправить её?

Comment: Похоже надо обратиться к хостеру, поскольку скрипт не может получить доступ к файлу вашей временной зоны.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Совсем забыл отписать вам о результатах. По итогу вы оказались правы, сделайте ваш совет ответом и я отмечу что он верный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая ошибка возникает, когда скрипт не может получить доступ к файлу временной зоны. Например, когда:

- скрипт работает в chroot-окружении
- у скрипта нет прав на чтение файла таймзоны
- не работает функция fopen
- неправильно указана таймзона в настройках